# Paypal IPN works in sandbox ipn sinulator but not in transactions

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My ipn script works when it is tested by paypal ipn simulator, but not with sandbox transactions, here is my paypal button

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
    method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="rslege_1359359492_biz@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Playershare">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://rspsdb.org/test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://rspsdb.org/paypal/ipn.php">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
        border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paypal's IPN stopped working at some point in the night/morning.

https://twitter.com/PayPalUK